# Wordpress AJAX HTML5 Geolocation (Error 400)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am having issues with using AJAX within Wordpress to obtain HTML5 Geolocation and output to a Google Maps Embed using `ajaxurl (admin-ajax.php)`.

Prior to including the `ajaxurl (admin-ajax.php)`, this worked (click `<a ...>Allow Location</a>`) and the embeded Google Map with longitude  and latitude was shown) but I couldn't get the longitude and latitude variables to pass to php without the use of `ajaxurl (admin-ajax.php)`. I need the variables in PHP so I can use them in other functions/processes.

**UPDATED**

I have updated the code below with the suggestions from @Parthavi-Patel. I had not linked `add_action( ..., 'audp_locate_book_request' );` by including `$.ajax data { action: 'audp_locate_book_request', ... }`. The code example below has been updated to be correct and operational.

**CUSTOM-PLUGIN.PHP**

```
public function audp_locate_book() {

    $post = get_post();

    if ( is_single('book') || ( is_single() && 'book' == $post->post_parent ) ) {

        wp_enqueue_script (
            'audp_locate_book',
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/audp-locate-book.js',
            array('jquery'),
            $this->version, // (Plugin uses Bootstrap)
            true
        );

        wp_localize_script(
            'audp_locate_book',
            'audp_locate_book_obj',
            array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
        );

    }

}

public function audp_locate_book_request() {

    if ( isset ( $_REQUEST ) ) {

        print_r( $_REQUEST );

        $longitude = $_REQUEST['longitude'];
        $latitude = $_REQUEST['latitude'];

    }

    wp_die();
}
    /**
     * Plugin uses bootstrap template. Alternatively you just use:
     * add_action( 'wp_enequeue_scripts, 'audp_locate_book' ); 
     * & repeat for other functions.
     */
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'audp_locate_book' );

    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_audp_locate_book_request', $plugin_public, 'audp_locate_book_request'); // Logged In
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_audp_locate_bookt_request', $plugin_public, 'audp_locate_book_request'); // Not Logged In
```

**AUDP-LOCATE-BOOK.JS**

```
(function($){

    $(function() {

        jQuery('a#geolocate').click(initiate_geolocation);

        // Initiate Geolocation
        function initiate_geolocation() {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocation_query,geolocation_errors);

        }

        // Output Geolocation
        function geolocation_query(position){

            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: audp_locate_book_obj.ajaxurl,
                data: { action: 'audp_locate_book_request', longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitude: position.coords.latitude },
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery("a#geolocate").html("Location Recorded").attr("disabled", true);
                    jQuery("p#map").html('<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&z=17&output=embed" width="100%" height="170" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');

                    console.log("Log: " + longitude + " & " + latitude);
                }

            });

        }

        // Geolocation Errors
        function geolocation_errors(error) {

            switch(error.code) {

                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("Location denied by user.");
                break;

                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("Location could not be detected.");
                break;

                case error.TIMEOUT: alert("Location request timed out.");
                break;

                default: alert("Unknown error.");
                break;

            }

        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

In Chrome Console, the error has come back with:

```
(x) POST: mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php      [400]
    send               @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
    ajax               @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
    geolocation_query  @ audp-locate-book.js?ver=1.0.0:23
```

Line:23 Refers To:

```
23:     $.ajax({
24:            type: "POST",
25:            url: audp_locate_book.ajaxurl,
... etc
```

**SINGLE-POST-TYPE.PHP**

```
<!-- Relevant Code -->
<a onClick="javascript:void(0);" id="geolocate" class="button primary expand"  >Allow Location</a>

<p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 9.5pt;" id="map"></p> <!-- Map No Longer Shows Here -->
<!-- End Relevant Code -->
```

Ultimately, my goal is to display the google maps embed with the longitude/latitude and also make the longitude and latitude a PHP variable (`$longitude`, `$latitude`) as I require it for other php functions within the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also pass action name in data  `action: 'audp_locate_book_request'`

```
      $.ajax({           
            type: "POST",
            url: audp_locate_book.ajaxurl,
            data: { action: 'audp_locate_book_request', longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitude: position.coords.latitude },
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery("a#geolocate").html("Location Recorded").attr("disabled", true);
                jQuery("p#map").html('<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&z=17&output=embed" width="100%" height="170" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');

                console.log("Log: " + longitude + " & " + latitude);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thank-you Parthavi. In addition to the function audp_locate_book_request(), how would I then output the variables (or any information for that matter) from that function back in to the page? I've tried var_dump($_REQUEST) and var_dump($longitude), etc but nothing is coming up?

Comment: You can check `post` data in "Network" tab. Just do `echo "<pre>"; print_r( $_POST ); die;`

Comment: before that make sure, you are getting proper values in these two variables.
`var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
 var latitude = position.coords.latitude;`